# "Scroll to Text" not working in Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, scroll-to-text

I've built a Chrome Extension (pop-up) and one of the primary functions is opening different web pages when the user clicks on a link.  Sometimes I want to focus on specific text on the new page so I'm trying to use the "scroll to text fragment" feature through my extension.

Unfortunately, when the page loads, this feature (scroll to text) fails.  I have tested the exact same link manually and it works fine, but when I inject this link into the browser through my extension, nothing happens except the page loading as normal.

Here are a few more details that might help:

1. The problem I'm having is using Chrome.tabs.update() which is triggered by a user clicking a link in my popup
2. We are using manifest v2 not v3
3. The exact command from the popup javascript is (not tab id as it defaults to current tab):
   `chrome.tabs.update({ url: "http://example.com/#:~:text=example", })`
4. In the manifest, we do not have the "tabs" permission.

Is there a special permission needed to use this feature in my extension?  Is there something I need to do in my extension code to make this work as expected?   I'm at a loss for next steps.

This is the exact feature I'm referring to: https://chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096

And here's an example of the feature in action:
[https://chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096#:~:text=Motivation-,Navigating%20to%20a%20URL,-today%20will%20load](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096#:%7E:text=Motivation-,Navigating%20to%20a%20URL,-today%20will%20load)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: @wOxxOm - more information added, included code, per your request.

Answer (score 1):

There's no special permission so apparently it's a bug in Chrome: [crbug.com/1241508](https://crbug.com/1241508)

**A simple workaround** is to use chrome.tabs.create and close the original tab, but it flickers in the tab strip and loses the tab's back/forward history, sessionStorage, and so on.

```js
function navigate(url) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    chrome.tabs.create({ url, index: tab.index });
  });
}
```

**Another workaround** is to set the hash part of the URL in the content script, but it requires host permissions for the navigated site in manifest.json like `*://example.com/`

```js
async function navigate(url) {
  if (await setUrlInContentScript(url)) {
    return true;
  }
  const [base, hash] = url.split('#');
  await onTabReceivedUrl(await new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.tabs.update({ url: base }, resolve);
  }));
  return setUrlInContentScript('#' + hash, 'hash');

  function setUrlInContentScript(url, part = 'href') {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: `location.${part}=${JSON.stringify(url)}`,
        runAt: 'document_start',
      }, () => resolve(!chrome.runtime.lastError));
    });
  }

  function onTabReceivedUrl(tab) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function onUpdated(tabId, info) {
        if (tabId === tab.id && info.url) {
          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm , were you able to recreate this bug on your end?  The workarounds are interesting but have their drawbacks as well that might make them not suitable for my current users.

Comment: Yes, and I've already submitted the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I discovered, that one of the characters `~` was encoded. You need the real characters to get *Scroll to Text* working.