# chrome.debugger.sendCommand doesn't work on extension but works on console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am testing the Chrome DevTools Protocol from a chrome extension, and I am having troubles making `Emulation.setFocusEmulationEnabled` work. This is my test extension:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "permissions": ["debugger", "tabs"]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.debugger.onDetach.addListener((source, reason) => {
    console.log("Debugger detached", source, reason);
});

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
    console.log("Attaching debugger", tab.id);
    chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tab.id }, "1.3", () => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log('runtime.lastError', tab.id, chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log("Debugger attached", tab.id);
        //setTimeout(() => {
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                tabId: tab.id
            }, "Emulation.setFocusEmulationEnabled", {
                enabled: true
            }, (result) => {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                }
                console.log('Command sent:', JSON.stringify(result));
            });
        //}, 2000);
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => { run() });
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(async () => { run() });

async function run() {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'about:blank', active: true, index: 0 }).then((tab) => {
        console.log(`Created tab ${tab.id}.`);
    });
}
```

To test it I load the unpacked extension, the extension opens a new tab, I press F12 to open the devtools and type `document.hasFocus()`, the result is `false`. Then I open `Settings > More Tools > Extensions` and inspect the service worker view. There I run:

```
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
            tabId: XX
        }, "Emulation.setFocusEmulationEnabled", {
            enabled: true
        }, (result) => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            }
            console.log('Command sent:', JSON.stringify(result));
        });
```

Replacing XX with the tab id that is shown in the console.logs, then I go back to the tab console, and now `document.hasFocus()` returns `true`.

**Why is it working when I run it from the console, but not from the extension?** I tried adding a setTimeout() to make sure the tab finishes being created, but got the same results.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. As a workaround, try waiting for the URL, see onTabReceivedUrl [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68852058).